# C swapping any pointers in an array by casting them to void pointers K&R

Tags: c, pointers

I have found many threads in regards to this, but not a response that elucidates my specific question.

So the section of K&R titled "Pointers to function" talks about turning an array of any pointers into an array of `void*` pointers, then passing this array to `qsort`, in order to be able to sort a generic array of items.

`qsort` uses a function called `swap` which swaps two of these `void*` pointers, effectively swapping what the positions in the array will be pointing at.

It achieves this via the common

```
void* tmp = v[i];
v[i] = v[j];
v[j] = tmp;
```

Here is my questions. Suppose the `v` passed in was an array of integer pointers, and suppose these are 4 bytes. In `swap` this array is represented as an array of `void*` pointers. When the function does `v[i] = ...` it offsets the location of the first element of `v` by `i*sizeof(void*)` and gets the element in this memory location. Correct? But what if `sizeof(void*)` is not the same as `sizeof(int*)`? Then `v[i]` will not get the the whole memory location containing the original `int*` and I am afraid to even postulate what will be returned. 
So how does `swap` account for this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please be clar. swapping (the contents of) pointers is very different from swapping the **contents of the objects** they point to.

Comment: "and suppose these are 4 bytes" you should have stopped thinking about that here already. What you appear to try leads soon to unmaintainable code.

Comment: It is swapping the pointers themselves, not the data that the pointers are pointing to

Comment: Are you talking about `qsort` from standard C library? It accepts the size of the elements in array and doesn't care about the actual types. It will swap those elements (for example) with `memcpy`. See [here for example](https://github.com/kraj/uClibc/blob/master/libc/stdlib/stdlib.c#L711).

Comment: @Banthar I know that if qsort accepts the size then all is good. I am reading the K&R book, and the qsort implementation they show doesn't take in the size, hence my question

Comment: Can you post the actual code from the book which sets up the array and invokes qsort? It's unclear from your description what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

> it offsets the location of the first element of `v` by `i*sizeof(void*)` and gets the element in this memory location. Correct?

Yes, it gets the location of the indexed element according to the usual pointer arithmetic using the size of an element, in this case a `void*`.

> But what if `sizeof(void*)` is not the same as `sizeof(int*)`? Then `v[i]` will not get the the whole memory location containing the original `int*` and I am afraid to even postulate what will be returned.

Indeed, `sizeof(void*)` is not required to be the same as `sizeof(int*)` (although it often is), and if the sizes are not the same, sooner or later you'll likely end up with undefined behaviour.

> So how does swap account for this?

It doesn't. The stdlib's [qsort](http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort), however, is different:

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
       int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

The `size` argument handles this issue by specifying how big each element is, allowing both sorting of non-pointer types, and passing void pointers that can be correctly converted back to the original type to the `compar()` function.

You could write a similar `swap()` yourself that accepted the size of the elements as a parameter, calculated the correct position, and swapped them using `memcpy()`.

Comment: thank you very much Iskar. That just cleared up everything.